Configuring Spring boot to prompt client certificate selection
I have a spring boot server (with react front end) that I'm attempting to configure to prompt the user for a certificate in certain use cases that may require additional authentication. The spring boot server already has token authentication, but I would like to configure one of the services to use certificates. What I'm going for is for something like the below image to appear in the browser when the user attempts to interact with this service.
Certificate prompt
This is what I have so far in my application.yml.
ssl:
    enabled: true
    key-store-type: "PKCS12"
    key-store: "classpath:springboot.p12"
    key-store-password: "<keystore-password>"
    client-auth: WANT 

The main requirement is that the user is prompted to select a certificate from the available client certificates installed in their browser. I'll also need to be able to read the certificate from the request once it arrives on the server. So far, I've only been able to get this prompt to appear when communicating with my spring server if I configure a trust store. Unfortunately, in this case the prompt only shows certificates that I've manually added to the trust store. To summarize, my main questions are:

Is there a way to configure SSL in Spring boot so that the user is prompted to select a certificate from any of the certificates that are installed in their browser?
Is it possible to set this process up to only occur in certain situations (E.G. a specific endpoint is called on the server)

